Multi master HA Kubernetes kubespray installation using kubevip fails
I'm trying to install a HA Kubernetes using Kubespray with Kube VIP. I followed the instruction of Kubespray for Kube VIP but it gets stuck on "TASK [kubernetes/control-plane : Kubeadm | Create kubeadm config]" until timeout and failure of the Kubespray and I can't even see the VIP when I run ip a.
Here is my configs of KubeVIP in addons.yml file:
# Kube VIP
kube_vip_enabled: true
kube_vip_arp_enabled: true
kube_vip_controlplane_enabled: true
kube_vip_address: 192.168.2.63 # It is on the same subnet that node IP's are.
loadbalancer_apiserver:
  address: "{{ kube_vip_address }}"
  port: 6443
kube_vip_interface: ens192 # This is the interface that the node actual IP uses. I also tried the Interface altname for this.
kube_vip_services_enabled: false

I have also set kube_proxy_strict_arp: true.
here is the kubelet log of the first node after failing the Kubespray:
Apr 24 22:00:00 knode1 kubelet[189461]: I0424 22:00:00.792273  189461 csi_plugin.go:880] Failed to contact API server when waiting for CSINode publishing: Get "https://lb-apiserver.kubernetes.local:6443/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1/csinodes/knode1": dial tcp 192.168.2.63:6443: connect: no route to host

And this is the output of kubectl cluster-info:
[root@knode1 ~]# kubectl cluster-info
E0424 22:03:11.381987  190751 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
E0424 22:03:11.382315  190751 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
E0424 22:03:11.383693  190751 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
E0424 22:03:11.384011  190751 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
E0424 22:03:11.385271  190751 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Did I misunderstood something or Did something wrong?
Many thanks in advance for you help.

It seems that for some reason, for the first cluster installation it does not work and I fixed it with the following steps:

Disabled the kube-vip in addons.yml and run the cluster.yml playbook for the first time installing the cluster.
After the cluster is deployed successfully, enabled kube-vip in addons.yml and run the cluster.yml playbook again (it updates the cluster with the new configurations).

Now everything is OK and the cluster is Highly Available:
[root@knode1 ~]# kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes control plane is running at https://lb-apiserver.kubernetes.local:6443

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.


did you also set the following settings for kube-vip? docs here https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/blob/v2.26.0/docs/ingress/kube-vip.md
### LoadBalancer for services
kube_vip_services_enabled: false
# kube_vip_services_interface: eth0
### Control Plane loadbalancing
# kube_vip_lb_enable: true```
